# Entity Framework model on matching databases with different case

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We are building a WPF application that uses Entity Framework 6 Database First and will be distributed to different databases.
Historically, these databases have grown apart and tables or columns sometimes differ in case, example below :

`Database 1` -`Table Customers` - `Column CustomerNumber`

`Database 2` - `Table customers` - `Column customernumber`

Is there any solution to be able to connect to both databases without changing the model for each database or fixing all database tables and columns?

Comment: What you meant by Connect ?

Comment: We will distribute the application (with the E.F. model included) on different machines, each with its own database to connect to. So the application will only connect to one database every time, but the table/column names can differ in case between these databases. I've edited my post.

Comment: My first impression on this is no, you are going to have to standardize. You would have to dig into the Entity Framework Metadata Workspace and dynamically regenerate the column names at runtime, but how would you detect when this is needed to be done, and for which tables?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259949/ef-6-0-change-table-name-at-runtime

Comment: Do you mean that you can't do it right now? Usually DML statements are not case sensitive.

Comment: @Claies: I'm afraid you're right. We don't know up front which tablenames and columnnames will differ from the 'standard'.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: The LINQ queries are written with the 'standard' naming convention, when we connect to a different database, an error is thrown because the fields don't match.