# Repeated Entity Framework Model Creation with Custom Table Name. Possible caching issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I've written a console app that archives data by month into separate SQL tables. Each table has identical schema, but different name with a different timestamp.

e.g. Readings_201610, Readings_201609

I'd like to iterate through the months, creating and disposing the DbContext which points the Readings class to a different table name each time. For some reason my approach works for the first database creation but doesn't appear to change the table name on the second iteration even though the context has been implicitly disposed and should be recreated.

Below is the trimmed down code for the DbContext itself, the table configuration that accepts the table name as an argument and the program that initialises the context in a loop. Any insight into why this is failing would be great.

As a side note, I'd really prefer this not to turn into a discussion on archiving techniques. I believe this to be a bug in some aspect of Entity Framework caching and I would really appreciate a work around/explanation.

The DbContext:

```
public class ReadingContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string tablePrefix;

    public ReadingContext(string tablePrefix) : base("name=ArchiveDatabase")
    {            
        this.tablePrefix = tablePrefix;
    }

    public DbSet<Reading> BackupReadings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BackupReadingsConfiguration(tablePrefix));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The table configuration:

```
public class BackupReadingsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Reading>
{
    public BackupReadingsConfiguration(string tablePrefix)
    {
        // Map the table name
        string tableName = "Readings";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tablePrefix))
        {
            tableName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", tableName, tablePrefix);
        }

        this.ToTable(tableName);
    }
}
```

The program:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
        string _tablePrefix;
        DateTime _startDateTime = Properties.Settings.Default.StartDate;
        DateTime _endDateTime = Properties.Settings.Default.EndDate;

        int _year = _startDateTime.Year;
        int _month = _startDateTime.Month;

        while (new DateTime(_year, _month, 1, 0, 0, 0) < _endDateTime.AddDays(1))
        {
            _tablePrefix = string.Concat(_year.ToString("D4"), _month.ToString("D2"));

            using (var readingContext = new ReadingContext(_tablePrefix))
            {
                // Do Something
                // First DbContext creation has correct table name, all subsequent DbContext creations the table name remains the same as the first.
            }

            _month = ++_month % 13;

            if (_month % 13 == 0)
            {
                _year = ++_year;
                _month = ++_month;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are targeting the same database, that means your first context will create the database with its known schema, and the others will see the schema is already correct and not change anything (I doubt this configuration will cause the database to be recreated). You'll have to add all into one context, use different databases or handle the schema yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it would have to be in the same database. Without the code becoming ridiculously messy I'm reluctant to add everything into one context, particularly as Entity Framework only allows use of a single class to be used for a single table (and all of the tables are identical). So I guess I've got to handle the schema myself, so any advice or resources for this would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't usually advocate this kind of solution but as its for a one-time use console application and the operations on the database are basic and the only change to the query created by EF is a table name change. I have decided to use an interceptor. Practically used the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32131789/2286396) by Eric Chhun.