# EntityFramework6 memory usage with large amount of table due to InitializedDatabases list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In our application there are a large amount of tables (around 50k) - all of those tables are actually used and this results in a high memory consumption in entity framework.

After some memory profiling I noticed that DbCompiledModel classes were being kept in memory so after some searching tracked it down to the LazyInternalContext class that keeps a list of "InitializedDatabases".

https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Internal/LazyInternalContext.cs#L670

Is there a way to prevent entity framework from doing this?, it's not a code first setup, database setup and migration are not done in this app if that is what the "InitializeDatabaseAction" implies.

Setting a "return null" or setting "InitializerDisabled" to true makes everything work but would rather not run a custom entity build plus don't know what the impact would be to just 'change' the source.

Most tables have the same definition so also tried the solution I found here:
[Change table name at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259949/change-table-name-at-runtime)

When trying this I'm getting an error "An open data reader exists for this command", using postgres and MARS isn't supported there (no idea why I'd need it, this just changes the sql that's run)

Comment: Try adding `AsNoTracking` to your queries. This prevents the entities from being cached. But this is a solution for read-only entities only. EF wants to register any change to every created entity , therefore it has maintain caches and copies. A change is determined, by storing the original object, and comparing it with the -may be modified- object. It needs the original to create the UPDATE command.

Comment: You content life span is too long....  but again to hard to say without what your implementation looks like, but my guess is your holding an instance of dbcontext for the life of you app, rather than a unit of work.

Comment: @Holger, this does not help as it's not the entities that are the problem. it's the model cache.

Comment: @Seabizkit, the context is disposed every time. The collection is static (see link to LazyInternalContext)

Comment: @Crazy thanks, is this related to if not apologies and will delete please include what version of EF you are using: code-first-startup-performance see links about using Using a cached db model store, never heard of this issue above LazyInternalContext...
https://entityframework.net/why-first-query-slow
https://www.fusonic.net/developers/2014/07/09/3-steps-for-fast-entity-framework-

Comment: @Seabizkit, both links don't help because it will still store all the dbcachedmodel classes in the List. Already have a custom dbcachedmodelstore. Didn't add this in the sample I'm using to test though. I'll add it just to be sure

Comment: @Crazy do you have Db Migrations and if so how many? I don't know but get the impression that this may be related to migrations now.

Comment: @Seabizkit, everything is database first - database migrations should be disabled, in the context I've set "Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);". I've referenced the entity framework source and stepping though the source I don't see a way to turn it off without a source code change in entity itself.

Comment: you probably better off posting your code, or minimal code which can reproduce the issue.

Comment: If it is not a code first setup, how do you use entity framework then?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik, the other way around.., having an existing database. This is just one application of many that uses this database

Comment: How many `DbCompiledModel` instances are kept in memory? Normally there should be only 1. Of course it will consume memory, but it's required for EF functioning (contains all the metadata/mappings) and creating it every time (with so many entities) will significantly slowdown the app.

Comment: @IvanStoev, agreed, I'm providing my own DbCompiledModels (so I can pick how much I cache). The "InitializedDatabases" list in entity is only used for "InitializeDatabaseAction" and nothing else, so far as I see it's only used for that list. When modifying the source and adding a return or setting "InitializerDisabled = true" everything keeps working just fine (as it should, I supply my own dbcachedmodel "cache")

Comment: @Crazy, you can also try pre-compiled views to boost up EF initial load.

Comment: @sam that isn't the problem, everything is fine except the high memory usage, the dbcompiledmodel are mostly between 500kb and 1 mb, so 50k x 0.5mb = 25gb - while the app could run with lets say 200 to 300mb memory usage - Entity is the rest

Comment: @Crazy, so you say, your DbContext has really 50.000 DbSets ? Really a strange situation. And they are all used at the same time ? Breaking things down to subsets might be an idea. Or summarize some relations to a stored view. It's not a problem if the DbContext is not reflecting your entire database structure.

Comment: @Crazy So you are using one of the `DbContext` constructors with `DbCompiledModel`, thus avoiding [this static model cache](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Internal/LazyInternalContext.cs#L41). But now `InitializedDatabases` caches them inside the key. From what I see, `InitializedDatabases` actions are used just to run `DbInitializer`s. If you use `Database.SetInitializer(null);` for your contexts, then I guess you can set `InternalContext.InitializerDisabled = true;` via reflection inside your context constructor.

Comment: @IvanStoev Correct, did the reflection trick and works. It's a shame reflection is needed for this. Hope this gets addressed in EF Core, at some point I'd like to switch to it but currently too much code (like the DbCompiledModels) is EF6 specific and doesn't work in core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was given in a comment bu Ivan Stoev and works.

There is no way to turn this off without using reflection, setting the "InternalContext.InitializerDisabled" property to true will make this skip the dictionary.

So:

- Use a DbContext constructor that provides the DbCachedModel
- Use Database.SetInitializer(null);
- Set InternalContext.InitializerDisabled = true using reflection

Code from the sample I used to test this, as a test setup I had 1 main table with 30k partitions, the partitions themselves are queried because postgres (especialy 9.x) does not scale well with high number of partitions:

```
    public class PartContext : DbContext {
        private static readonly string _ConnectionString = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder {
            Host = "localhost",
            Port = 5432,
            Database = "postgres",
            Username = "postgres",
            Password = "password"
        }.ConnectionString;

        public readonly string Table;
        public readonly string Partition;

        public PartContext(string pMainTable, string pPartition) : base(
            new NpgsqlConnection() { ConnectionString = _ConnectionString },
            PartDbModelBuilder.Get(_ConnectionString, pPartition),
            true
        ) {
            Table = pMainTable;
            Partition = pPartition;

            Database.SetInitializer<PartContext>(null);


            /**
             * Disable database initialization so that the DbCachedModels are not kept internally in Entity
             * This causes high memory usage when having a lot of tables 
             * In EF 6.4.2 there was no way to 'manage' that Dictionary externally
             */
            try {
                var InternalContext = typeof(PartContext).BaseType.GetProperty("InternalContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this, null);
                InternalContext.GetType().GetProperty("InitializerDisabled").SetValue(InternalContext, true);
            } catch(Exception) { }
        }

        public DbSet<MyPart> Parts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

This provides the DbCachedModels:

I recommend adding some custom caching code etc, this is just from a sample

```
    class PartDbModelBuilder {
        public static DbCompiledModel Get(string pConnectionString, string pTable) {
            DbModelBuilder builder = new DbModelBuilder();
            builder.Entity<MyPart>().ToTable(pTable, "public");
            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection() { ConnectionString = pConnectionString }) {
                var obj = builder.Build(connection).Compile();
                return obj;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the entity I used as a test:

```
    public class MyPart {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

Class I used to run the test:

```
    class EFTest {
        public void Run(int tableCount) {
            int done = 0;
            Parallel.For(0, tableCount, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, (i) => {
                string id = i.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
                using (var context = new PartContext("mypart", "mypart_" + id)) {
                    var objResult = context.Parts.First();
                    Console.WriteLine(objResult.name);
                }
                done++;
                Console.WriteLine(done + " DONE");
            });
        }
    }
```

Table definition:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mypart (
        id SERIAL,
        name text,
        value text
    ) partition by list (name);

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS part partition of mypart_00000 for values in ('mypart00000');
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS part partition of mypart_00001 for values in ('mypart00001');
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS part partition of mypart_00002 for values in ('mypart00002');
    ...
```

Postgres 9:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mypart (
        id SERIAL,
        name text,
        value text
    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$name."( CHECK ( name =  'mypart00000')) INHERITS (mypart);
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$name."( CHECK ( name =  'mypart00001')) INHERITS (mypart);
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$name."( CHECK ( name =  'mypart00002')) INHERITS (mypart);
    ...
```

Comment: what are you doing with ` Table = pMainTable;
            Partition = pPartition; ` seems like you are using EF in an either amazing way or very incorrect, which is making your life harder than it needs to be.

Comment: if you create partitions, then just use Ef normally would the db not just handle partitioning the data anyway seems over the top to start specify thing which it does internal, based on the partition value, aka name.

Comment: @Seabizkit Postgres doesn't scale well with lots of partitions - I'm talking about between 10 and 30k partitions, per setup - and that'll only grow. I have no control over the database, so I'm stuck with it as is. Postgres 11 is much beter in it then the 9.5 that's being used in my case, but querying on the main table is still a very bad idea.

Comment: mmm im guessing i don't know enough around this. but what I'm seeing you are over complicate it for 0 benefit. strip it down to the basics 1 query what does the query look like, how is it different from what Ef would generate. yeah i get you are doing things in Parallel and what not but that really doesnt change much you can still do all that without over complicating things.... i can see why they look over the top cant see the value add... everything you have done could of been done with vanilla

Comment: does it modify the connection string to include partitions, or does it append something to the query as a hint for partitions. i can see you passing values but what is the net result.

Comment: The query on command line is also slow when doing them on the main table, that's why where're querying the partitions directly. The partitioning is done by the column name(list), when a select is done with "where name = 'x'" it queries the correct partition. The above example is for postgres10/11.