# Set dynamic table name(database table) to one single entity in EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have many tables with the same model structure but with table names and data is different.

E.g

```cs
//Model

public class pgl1
{
   public string id {get;set;}
   public string name {get;set;}
} 

public class pgl2
{
   public string id {get;set;}
   public string name {get;set;}
}
```

My tables in database are `pgl_1`, `pgl_2`, `pgl_3` etc...

Context class -

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<pgl1>? pgl_1{ get; set; } //pgl_1 is database table name
    public DbSet<pgl2>? pgl_2{ get; set; } //pgl_2 is database table name
}
```

And I will implement this using below.

```cs
var context = new MyContext();

List<<*pgl1>> list1 = new List<<*pgl1>>();

listb = context.pgl1.ToList<<*pgl1>>();

List<<*pgl2>> list2 = new List<<*pgl2>>();

list2 = context.pgl2.ToList<*pgl2>>();
```

I want only one Model and one Dbset for multiple tables.

Is this possible.

I have searched lot for this but did not get any proper solution.

Any answers will really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259949/change-table-name-at-runtime) answer your question?

Comment: Maybe you do not need EF? It is not designed to work in such dynamic environment. `linq2db` will handle that with ease.

Comment: EF is an ORM - it Maps Objects to Relational tables. A DbSet<T> doesn't represent a database table, it represents an application Entity. Besides, why do you have so many tables? How do you know which table to pick each time? Perhaps EF already handles your *real* problem, just not in the way you assumed?

Comment: Why do you have so many identical tables to begin with? To implement inheritance? Partitioning? Multi-tenancy? All of those can be handled in cleaner ways. EF already supports inheritance. Partitioning is a database matter and most of the time you *don't* need to have multiple tables. For example all supported versions of SQL Server have table partitioning, even the Express editions. There's no reason to use `pg_2022` and `pg_2021`. Multitenancy can be handled with interceptors, global query filters or dynamic connection strings with DbContextFactory

Comment: In SQL Server (and most databases) you can also use [partitioned views](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/09/partitioned-views-guide/) to combine the data from all the tables, so EF only has to map to that view

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that table for entity sets up in `OnModelCreating` method which executes right after your database context is instantiated on incoming http request and you can't change it after.

The simplest workaround here is do not use entity-to-model binding in `OnModelCreating`, but write your own CRUD methods in your `DbContext` implementation, which would use `tableName` argument to dynamically build SQL query string.

```cs
base.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"INSERT INTO {tableName} ...");
```